# How the copy only backup affect the regular daily full backup ? what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using full backup which is scheduled daily. Each day changes has been done in big level so that i choose full backup. what will be the major changes if i choose copy only backup while taking the full backup ? Actually i need to speed up the backup process and how could the copy only back will be affect the actual full backup process?

Answer (score 0):

Copy only backup are similar to full backup (they backup the entire database) however they won't have any impact on DatabaseBackupLSN. They will not speed up your backup process. You can consider differential backups to backup only the changed data which can be faster compared to full backup (unless entire data is changed).